# Move QGraphicsItem to QGraphicsItemGroup position

Tags: python, pyqt

i'm trying to understand if there is a way to move the position of an object inside a QGraphicsItemGroup.

for example, i want to create a GraphItemGroup and assign some coordinates on the scene. Then when an event happens add some items from the scene into the group and all items that were added to the group will move inside the center.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import ( 
    QWidget, QStyleOptionGraphicsItem,QGraphicsView, 
    QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsItem, QApplication, QGraphicsItemGroup, 
    QGraphicsEllipseItem) 
import json
import math
from random import randrange

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets,sip

from PyQt5.QtCore import (
    Qt,
    QRectF,
    QRect,
)
from PyQt5.QtGui import (
    QPainter,
    QBrush,
    QPen,
    QColor,
)
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QWidget,
    QGraphicsItemGroup,
    QGraphicsItem
)

import time

class MyDisk(QGraphicsEllipseItem):
    def __init__(self, top_left_x, top_left_y, radius, color):
        super().__init__(top_left_x, top_left_y, radius, radius)
        self.setBrush(color)
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)


class MyGroup(QGraphicsItemGroup):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItemGroup.ItemIsMovable)
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItemGroup.ItemIsMovable)

    def boundingRect(self) -> QRectF:
        return QRectF(100,100,40,40)
    
    def paint(self,
              painter: QtGui.QPainter,
              option: QStyleOptionGraphicsItem,
              widget: QWidget = None):
        painter.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.NoPen))
        painter.setBrush(QtGui.QBrush(QtCore.Qt.gray))
        #painter.drawRect(QRect(100,100,20,20))
        r = self.boundingRect()
        painter.drawRect(QRect(r.x(), r.y(), r.width(), r.height()))



class MyView(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.scene = QGraphicsScene()
        self.setScene(self.scene)
        self.setWindowTitle('Red disks are not movable')
        self.setSceneRect(0, 0, 250, 250)
        self.group = MyGroup()
        self.scene.addItem(self.group)
        d1 = MyDisk(0, 0, 20, Qt.green)
        d2 = MyDisk(150, 50, 20, Qt.red)
        d3 = MyDisk(150, 80, 20, Qt.blue)
        self.scene.addItem(d1)
        self.scene.addItem(d2)
        self.scene.addItem(d3)
        #self.group.addToGroup(d1) // not working either
        #self.group.addToGroup(d2) // no working either
        d2.setParentItem(self.group)
        d1.setParentItem(self.group)
  


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    f = MyView()
    f.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

the code above creates the objects and the group. Then assigns the items to the group , but i don't see them changing position 'inside the group'.

Is there a way to achieve this ? or do i have to iterate over the items , then ->setPos() ?

Comment: Adding items to a group doesn't make them display "inside" it, as the groups' bounding rect should reflect the items it contains, while you're changing that behavior trying to get the opposite. It seems like you're trying to use QGraphicsItemGroup for the wrong purpose, so I strongly suggest you to read more carefully its documentation, along with that of QGraphicsItem, and the graphics view [coordinate system](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/graphicsview.html#the-graphics-view-coordinate-system).

Comment: fair enough. thanks for the pointers...back to drawing board in this case

Answer (score 0):

the workaround here ( based on @musicamante explanation) is to take the position of the curson on the scene , iterate over all nodes i want in the group ->set.pos(screenX,screenY) then add them to group that has the bounding rect as below.

```
self.childrenBoundingRect().adjusted(-25, -25, 50, 50)
```